# How to add restrictions in image transformation tools in photoeditorsdk

Tags: reactjs, image, photoeditorsdk

I have been trying to find a solution to add certain restrictions listed below but unable to find any supportive content in the documentation.

1. Fixing resolution to 1920*1080 and restricting user from changing resolution.
2. User should not able to select any of the options in transform tools.
3. Restricting user from adjusting the grip size via drag.

I have tried certain options like transform ratios, adding a custom aspect ratio with resolution and restricting user to select only that size.
It seems nothing is working as per my expectations.